# Matplotlib 3D scatterplot animation using Python is not giving errors, but it is not working either

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, simulator, graphing

I'm trying to write an [N-body simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation), and I've run into a bit of a roadblock with Matplotlib's animation capabilities. I'm not entirely sure how to update the data inside the scatter plot, so I think that might be where the problem is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation
system = []
xlist = []
ylist = []
zlist = []
poslist = []
nbodies = 3
scale = 100
mass = 0
timestep = 0.1
step = 0.01
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
i = 1
plt.ion()
scat = ax.scatter(xlist, ylist, zlist, c='r', marker='o', animated=True)
class Body:
    def __init__(self, posvel, mass):
        self.state = np.zeros((3, 3))
        self.state[0:2] = posvel * scale
        self.state[2] = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        self.mass = mass
    def setPos(self, pos):
        self.state[0] = pos
    def setVel(self, vel):
        self.state[1] = vel
    def setAcc(self, acc):
        self.state[2] = acc
    def getPos(self):
        return self.state[0]
    def getVel(self):
        return self.state[1]
    def getAcc(self):
        return self.state[2]
def startSystem():
    for i in range(0,nbodies):
        system.append(Body(np.random.rand(2,3), np.random.random_sample()))
        curpos = system[i].getPos()
        xlist.append(curpos[0])
        ylist.append(curpos[1])
        zlist.append(curpos[2])
def stepSystem():
    xlist = []
    ylist = []
    zlist = []
    poslist = []
    for i in range(0,nbodies):
        curpos = system[i].getPos()
        system[i].setPos(curpos + 1*step)
        poslist.append(curpos + 1*step)
        xlist.append(curpos[0] + 1*step)
        ylist.append(curpos[1] + 1*step)
        zlist.append(curpos[2] + 1*step)
    yield xlist, ylist, zlist
def simPoints(stepSystem):
    xlist, ylist,zlist = stepSystem[0], stepSystem[1], stepSystem[2]
    scat.set_offsets(poslist)
    return scat
def Plot():
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, stepSystem, blit=False,\
     interval=100, repeat=True)
    plt.show()
def main():
    startSystem()
    Plot()
```

Comment: One apparently working example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9416663/3088138

Comment: The apparent problem is that you intend `xlist, ylist, zlist` as list of the coordinates of the points, but you do not use them. `scat.set_offsets` expects a list of 3D points `[ x[i], y[i], z[i] ]`. There is also an unfortunate  mix in the use of global and local variables (resp. function arguments).

Comment: Can you reduce this to a more minimal example?  There is way too much code here.  You also probably need to keep a reference to the returned animation object, see discussion here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1656

Comment: There appears to exist no "good" solution, `set_offsets' is for 2D plots, '_offsets3d = ( xlist, ylist, zlist)` (or with np.ma.ravel, seehttp://stackoverflow.com/q/11376898/3088138) is described as a hack http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/3d-animated-scatter-plot-td39721.html