# dynamically changing python plots

Tags: python

I want to plot data and view the graph in Python while the program is running, and hence, while the data is changing ; while executing loop and before the program completes execution. I am running genetic algorithm and I would like to view statistical data of each generation as and when each generation completes and before next generation begins.Does anyone know something I could use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your environment.

If it's web-based (or even if localhost server + browser is ok), then post your data as JSON and plot with in javascript using e.g. http://www.flotcharts.org/

If you want to use matplotlib for consistency with other plotting needs, then [How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot) covers your question and is well-answered.

Finally you may choose to make your own UI, in which case SVG, SDL, GTK+, Cairo are all valid options.

Comment: I am currently using Python 2.7.6 with Matplotlib, pylab and numpy. All that I am able to get is a scatterplot of every generation together. What I need is to get plot for each generation separately while erasing the plot of the previous generation. Thus the plot should ideally get updated after each generation.

Answer (score 0):

To add on what has been said so far, you can make use of [matplotlib.animation](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fapi%2Fanimation_api.html&ei=mTk9VNiwOtityATN6oKoDg&usg=AFQjCNF8x41FgR3Zl49pCdGVj_ZttWlZfg&sig2=M_BMGTrm0bT138cS3IDH0w&bvm=bv.77161500,d.aWw). There is a good demonstration using a scatter plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/matplotlib-animating-a-scatter-plot).
Regarding deleting handle, you can do it as simple as this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = None

for i in range(3):
    data = np.random.rand(100,2) 
    if h is not None:
        h.remove()
    h, = plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], 'oy')
    plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: I am taking input from a text file for plotting.But I am facing an issue. I want to generate plots as and when the generations are changing. But now I am only able to plot all generations together. Is there any way to take parts of data from a text file and then plot rather than consider whole data in text file together?

Comment: If the data doesn't create burden in memory, You can load the whole data in to a variable and plot part of this data in each loop.