# Colormap in Matplotlib without using the "scatter" function

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I have constructed a scatter plot with x and y positions. Now I have an array with a third variable, density, and I want to assign a color for each point in my scatter plot depending on its density value. I know how to do it using the "scatter" task of matplotlib, for example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,3,7,1]
density = [1,2,3,4]

map = plt.scatter(x, y, c=density)
colorbar = plt.colorbar(map)
```

Now, I would like to do the same using the "plot" function instead, something like:

```
map = plt.plot(x,y, '.', c=t)
```

I am trying to do an animation of a galaxy merger, and assign each particle a color depending of the density of that region. So far the code only works with the "plot" task, so I need to implement it that way, but all the examples I've found use the former way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To use `plot` everything must be the same color (due to the way it works underneath at the Agg layer).  I think you might be looking for the `set_offsets` method on `Collection` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, @tcaswell is right. You're probably wanting to [animate a `scatter` plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416663/325565). Using lots of `plot` calls for this will result in much worse performance than changing the collection that `scatter` returns.

However, here's how you'd go about using multiple `plot` calls to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata, ydata, zdata = np.random.random((3, 10))

cmap = plt.cm.gist_earth
norm = plt.Normalize(zdata.min(), zdata.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for x, y, z in zip(xdata, ydata, zdata):
    ax.plot([x], [y], marker='o', ms=20, color=cmap(norm(z)))

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap)
sm.set_array(zdata)
fig.colorbar(sm)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here's the exact same thing using `scatter`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata, ydata, zdata = np.random.random((3, 10))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=zdata, s=200, marker='o')
fig.colorbar(scat)

plt.show()
```

If you wanted to change the position of the markers in the scatter plot, you'd use `scat.set_offsets(xydata)`, where `xydata` is an Nx2 array-like sequence.