# Animate scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jquery-animate, scatter

I'm building a Python tool for visualizing data structures in 3D. The code below is the full program, it's even set up to run a default test model with some random data; you just need numpy and matplotlib. Basically, you declare a Node, connect it to other Nodes, and it makes pretty 3D networks. I'd like to be able to call switchNode() and have it flip the color of a node between black and white. With the way it works right now, every time a Node is instantiated, the plot is added to with another data point. I'm not familiar enough with matplotlib's animation tools to know the best way of doing this (my attempt at following the example from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/matplotlib-animating-a-scatter-plot) is commented out on line 83, and hoped someone could offer me some tips. Thanks!!

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim


# user-defined variables
debug = False
axisOn = False
labelsOn = True
maxNodes = 20
edgeColor = 'b'
dottedLine = ':'
darkGrey = '#191919'
lightGrey = '#a3a3a3'
plotBackgroundColor = lightGrey
fontColor = darkGrey
gridColor = 'k'
numFrames = 200



# global variables
fig = None
hTable = []
ax = None
numNodes = 0

# initialize plot
def initPlot():
    global ax, fontColor, fig
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', axisbg=plotBackgroundColor)
    if axisOn == False:
        ax.set_axis_off()
    else:
        ax.set_axis_on()
        fontColor = darkGrey

# gives n random float values between vmin and vmax
def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax - vmin) * np.random.rand(n) + vmin

# builds an empty node with a given value, helper method for makeNode
def makeNodeS(value):
    global hTable, numNodes
    n = Node(value)
    hTable.append(n)
    numNodes = len(hTable)
    return n

# builds a node with given parameters
def makeNode(value, location, color, marker):
    n = makeNodeS(value)
    n.setLoc(location)
    n.setStyle(color, marker)
    if debug:
        print("Building node {} at {} with color = {}, marker = {}, and associations = {}.".format(value, location, color, marker, n.assocs))
    return n

# aggregate nodes in hTable and plot them in 3D
def plotNodes():
    global hTable
    if debug:
        print("Plotting Graph...")
    for elem in hTable:
        if debug:
            print(" Plotting node {}...".format(elem.value))
        global fig, numFrames
        scat = ax.scatter(elem.location[0], elem.location[1], elem.location[2], c=elem.color, marker=elem.marker)

        for c in elem.assocs:
            if (getNode(c).value != elem.value):
                if elem.count in getNode(c).assocs:   # if the two nodes are associated to each other, draw solid line
                    ax.plot([elem.location[0], getNode(c).location[0]], [elem.location[1], getNode(c).location[1]], [elem.location[2], getNode(c).location[2]], edgeColor)
                    if debug:
                        print("  Plotting double edge between {} and {}...".format(elem.value, getNode(c).value))
                else:
                    ax.plot([elem.location[0], getNode(c).location[0]], [elem.location[1], getNode(c).location[1]], [elem.location[2], getNode(c).location[2]], edgeColor + dottedLine)
                    if debug:
                        print("  Plotting single edge from {} to {}...".format(elem.value, getNode(c).value))

    #ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=xrange(numFrames), fargs=(['b', 'w'], scat))

# build single connection from node A to node B
def sConnect(nodeA, nodeB):
    nodeA.addAssoc(nodeB)
    if debug:
        print(" Drawing single connection from node {} to node {}...".format(nodeA.value, nodeB.value))

# build double connection from node A to node B, and from node B to node A
def dConnect(nodeA, nodeB):
    if debug:
        print("\nDouble node connection steps:")
    sConnect(nodeA, nodeB)
    sConnect(nodeB, nodeA)

# update scatter with new color data
def update_plot(i, data, scat):
    scat.set_array(data[i])
    return scat

# returns the node with given count
def getNode(count):
    global hTable
    n = hTable[count-1]
    return n

# set up axis info
def defineAxis():
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.xaxis.label.set_color(lightGrey)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors=lightGrey)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.yaxis.label.set_color(lightGrey)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=lightGrey)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
    ax.zaxis.label.set_color(lightGrey)
    ax.tick_params(axis='z', colors=lightGrey)

# randomly populate nodes and connect them
def test():
    for i in range (0, maxNodes):
        rand = np.random.rand(2)
        if (0 <= rand[0] <= 0.25):
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'r', '^')
        elif (0.25 < rand[0] <= 0.5):
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'b', 'o')
        elif (0.5 < rand[0] <= 0.75):
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'g', 'v')
        elif (0.75 < rand[0]):
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'w', 'o')

        if (0 < i < maxNodes-1):
            if (rand[1] <= 0.2):
                dConnect(q, getNode(q.count-1))
            elif (rand[1] < 0.5):
                sConnect(q, getNode(q.count-1))

# randomly populate binary nodes and connect them
def test2():
    for i in range (0, maxNodes):
        rand = np.random.rand(2)
        if (0 <= rand[0] <= 0.80):
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'k', 'o')
        else:
            q = makeNode(i, np.random.rand(3), 'w', 'o')
        if (i > 0):
            if (rand[1] <= 0.2):
                dConnect(q, getNode(q.count-1))
            elif (rand[1] > 0.2):
                sConnect(q, getNode(q.count-1))

# switches a binary node between black and white
def switchNode(count):
    q = getNode(count)
    if (q.color == 'b'):
        q.color = 'w'
    else:
        q.color = 'b'

# main program
def main():
    ## MAIN PROGRAM

    initPlot()

    test2()

    plotNodes()

    defineAxis()

    plt.show()

# class structure for Node class
class Node(str):
    value = None
    location = None
    assocs = None
    count = 0
    color = None
    marker = None

    # initiate node
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        global numNodes
        numNodes += 1
        self.count = numNodes
        self.assocs = []
        self.color = 'b'
        self.marker = '^'

    # set node location and setup 3D text label
    def setLoc(self, coords):
        self.location = coords
        global labelsOn
        if labelsOn:
            ax.text(self.location[0], self.location[1], self.location[2], self.value, color=fontColor)

    # define node style
    def setStyle(self, color, marker):
        self.color = color
        self.marker = marker

    # define new association
    def addAssoc(self, newAssociation):
        self.assocs.append(newAssociation.count)
        if debug:
            print("  Informing node association:   Node {} ->  Node {}".format(self.value, newAssociation.value))

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatter returns a [collection](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/collections_api.html) and you can change the colors of the points in a collection with set_facecolor. Here's an example you can adapt for your code:

```
plt.figure()
n = 3
# Plot 3 white points.
c = [(1,1,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,1)]
p = plt.scatter(np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n), c = c, s = 100)
# Change the color of the second point to black. 
c[1] = (0,0,0)
p.set_facecolor(c)
plt.show()
```