# Matplotlib: Want to dynamically draw the plot by updating the c variable as I iterate overdata

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to draw a 3d heatmap by drawing a 3d scatter plot where the color of each data point corresponds to how often it occurs. I want to increment the values in "freq" as the program reads my data and dynamically update the graph. There are functions like ".set_xdata()" to update the scatter plot's "x" but I couldn't find a similar function to update the scatter plot's "c". This is what I'm currently doing and it's slow and crashes after a while:

```
location = 0
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    location = row[4]+4*row[5]+16*row[6]
    color_freq[location] += 1
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=color_freq, s=300)
    ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
    fig.canvas.update()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Instead of doing "ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=color_freq, s=300)" I would like to just update the "c" variable. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `set_data` or `set_array`

Comment: You should have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/matplotlib-animating-a-scatter-plot).