# Python plotting a scatter plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
    def twomasses(M1,M2,x1,x2,p,h,n): 
    global gamma
    global m1
    global m2 
    gamma = 1
    m1 = M1
    m2 = M2
    x0_1 = [1, 2]
    x0_2 = [4, 5]
    p = 3
    v1 = [0, p/m1]
    v2 = [0, -p/m2]

    def F(x1, x2):
        Fa = ((gamma*m1*m2)/(la.norm((x2 - x1),2) ** 3))*(x2 - x1)
        return Fa

    def a1(f, m1):
        a1 = f/m1
        return a1

    def a2(f, m2):
        a2 = f/m2
        return a2

    def ruku_step(F, y, h): #first ruku step

        k1 = F(y)
        k2 = F(y + (h/2)*k1)
        k3 = F(y + (h/2)*k2)
        k4 = F(y + h*k3)

        y = y + (h/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

        return y

    f = lambda y: np.array([y[2],y[3],a1(F(y[0],y[1]),m1),a2(F(y[0],y[1]),m2)])
    y = list()
    y.append(np.array([x0_1,x0_2, v1, v2]))
    for i in range(0,n):
        y.append(ruku_step(f, np.array(y[i]), h))
    return y

y = twomasses(1,2,-1,2,5,.1, 50)


maxy = np.max([e[0:2,1] for e in y])
maxx = np.max([e[0:2,0] for e in y])
minx = np.min([e[0:2,0] for e in y])
miny = np.min([e[0:2,1] for e in y])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def animate(t):
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(y[t][0:2,0],y[t][0:2,1])
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, frames=100) 
plt.show()
```

I want to animate the graph so that you can see the movement of the masses. I tried following [How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot) but it is quite complex and wouldnt run for me. This will refresh the graph each time new points are introduced, but I want them all within one graph.

Comment: Where is `y` defined?

Comment: `t` is a float. `linspace` is not really fit for integers.

Comment: I added the rest of my code

Comment: @undergrad Don't edit your question with the solution that you have found. You should post it as an answer instead

Comment: my answer is not the answer you posted. post yourself an answer and choose that one. (i can't delete mine now)

Answer (score 0):

lots of problems here: bad indent, `linspace` feeds floats and some parts of your code seem useless. but hey, it moves

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from numpy import linalg as la

def twomasses(M1,M2,x1,x2,p,h,n):
    global gamma
    global m1
    global m2
    gamma = 1
    m1 = M1
    m2 = M2
    x0_1 = [1, 2]
    x0_2 = [4, 5]
    p = 3
    v1 = [0, p/m1]
    v2 = [0, -p/m2]

    def F(x1, x2):
        Fa = ((gamma*m1*m2)/(la.norm((x2 - x1),2) ** 3))*(x2 - x1)
        return Fa

    def a1(f, m1):
        a1 = f/m1
        return a1

    def a2(f, m2):
        a2 = f/m2
        return a2

    def ruku_step(F, y, h): #first ruku step

        k1 = F(y)
        k2 = F(y + (h/2)*k1)
        k3 = F(y + (h/2)*k2)
        k4 = F(y + h*k3)

        y = y + (h/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

        return y

    f = lambda y: np.array([y[2],y[3],a1(F(y[0],y[1]),m1),a2(F(y[0],y[1]),m2)])
    y = list()
    y.append(np.array([x0_1,x0_2, v1, v2]))
    for i in range(0,n):
        y.append(ruku_step(f, np.array(y[i]), h))
    return y

y = twomasses(1,2,-1,2,5,.1, 50)
#~ print(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def animate(t):
    xdata = y[t][0:2,0]
    ydata = y[t][0:2,1]
    #~ def update(frame):
        #~ xdata.append(frame)
        #~ ydata.append(frame)
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'bs', animated=True)
maxy = np.max([e[0:2,1] for e in y])
maxx = np.max([e[0:2,0] for e in y])
minx = np.min([e[0:2,0] for e in y])
miny = np.min([e[0:2,1] for e in y])
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(minx-1, maxx+1)
    ax.set_ylim(miny-1, maxy+1)
    return ln,
ani =FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(len(y)),
    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```