# Matplotlib animation function: plots points but no animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing a short script in Python that is supposed to graph a series of scatter Cartesian points, one at a time as an animation (i.e., one frame is a point, the next frame is another). I'm using matplotlib.

My program currently plots correctly, but it returns a static plot with all the points on the plot, so something must be wrong with the animation function itself.

When I run the code now, despite returning a plot I receive AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_data'. I've tried tweaking several small things, but generally that error message remains the same. Thank you in advance!

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation 
import numpy as np

pole_list = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,3), (3,2), (3,1), (4,1), (3,1)] #arbitrary list of points

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x_val = [x[0] for x in pole_list]
y_val = [x[1] for x in pole_list]
scatterplot = ax.scatter(x_val, y_val)
print(x_val, y_val)

def init():
    scatterplot.set_data([], [])
    return scatterplot,

def animate(i, x_val, y_val):
    scatterplot.set_data(x_val, y_val)
    return scatterplot,


animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(x_val,y_val), init_func=init, frames=8, interval=20, blit = True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Python error messages are *helpful*. In this case it tells you that there is no `set_data` method for scatter plots. So the next step would probably be to google for something like "matplotlib animate scatter", which will directly lead you to e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot) for which I marked this as duplicate now.