# How to include the colormap as an iterator for a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, iterator, colormap

I have a set of (xyz) points and I am plotting them in a scatter plot.
This set of points evolves in time, therefore, an iterator is used to update each step.
At the moment, I am able to extract the maximum elevation (in the Z direction) of my plot, in order to define the max/min values and normalize the color map.
However, I do not know how to link the value of the elevation of my plot to the color map (defined previously) once the step is updated.

Right now, the code works without updating the colors.
I was trying to include the variable colormap as an iterator, but I couldn't find the commands to perform this task.

```
#Python moduels
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.animation
import pandas as pd

###############################################################################
#Generate data
###############################################################################

np.random.seed(10) #To obtain the same result

n_radii  = 8
n_angles = 120

# Make radii and angles spaces (radius r=0 omitted to eliminate duplication).
radii = np.linspace(0.125, 1.0, n_radii)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)

# Repeat all angles for each radius.
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)

# Convert polar (radii, angles) coords to cartesian (x, y) coords.
# (0, 0) is manually added at this stage,  so there will be no duplicate
# points in the (x, y) plane.
x = np.append(0, (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten())
y = np.append(0, (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten())

rows = len(x)
dim = 3
samples = 10

data = np.zeros((rows,dim,samples)) # (20 xyz) points stored in 10 sets 

for i in range(samples):
    data[:,0,i] = x
    data[:,1,i] = y
    # Compute z to make the pringle surface.
    data[:,2,i] = np.sin(-i*x*y)

index = np.arange(0,samples,1)

Frame = np.array([np.ones(rows)*index[i] for i in range(samples)]).flatten()

a = np.zeros((len(Frame),3))

for i in range(samples):
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,0] = data[:,0,i]
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,1] = data[:,1,i]
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,2] = data[:,2,i]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Frame": Frame ,"x" : a[:,0], "y" : a[:,1], "z" : a[:,2]})

##############################################################################
#SCATTER PLOT
################################################################################

#Function to update my scatter plot
def update_graph(num):

    data = df[df['Frame'] == index[num]]
    graph._offsets3d = (data.x, data.y, data.z)
    title.set_text(r'How to update the color map for each plot based on the value of, Frame={}'.format(round(index[num],3)))

#Limits of Elevation (U3) in data
print('U3_min',min(a[:,2]))
print('U3_max',max(a[:,2]))

#Define figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=200)

title = plt.suptitle(r'How to update the color map for each plot based on the value of, Frame={}'.format(round(index[0],3), fontsize=16))

# cmap will generate a tuple of RGBA values for a given number in the range 0.0 to 1.0 
# (also 0 to 255 - not used in this example).
# To map our z values cleanly to this range, we create a Normalize object.
cmap      = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
normalize = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(data[:,2,-1]), vmax=max(data[:,2,-1]))
colors = [cmap(normalize(value)) for value in data[:,2,-1]]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(45,30)
ax1.set_xlabel('X (mm)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y (mm)')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z Elevation (mm)')

data=df[df['Frame']==1]
graph = ax1.scatter(data.x, data.y, data.z, color=colors)

## Optionally add a colorbar
cax, _ = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax1, shrink=0.5)
cbar   = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=normalize)

#Animation
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, samples, 
                               interval=40, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

In the attached file, the colormap is defined for the last frame of the problem, where U3max=1 and U3min=-1. For example, during the first step (frame=0), there is no elevation, therefore, in the 'coolwarm' scale, the plot should be white, but it takes the values of blue and red as well.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The colormap is constant. Is this desired or not? I really have problems to understand what you would like to achieve at the end compared to what you have now, especially, since the code makes no attempt to change the colors in the animation

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for your comment. In order to clarify my post, it is required to define a "global" colormap that is constant (done), in order to be used as a reference for each frame. Now, the problem is that: a) I do not know how to update the "local" colormap (referred to each frame) or b) how to link the local colormap respect to the global one. It means one that I know the U3max/min values (in this case 1 and -1) Now, there is always blue/red colors for the local max/min while they do not correspond to the global max/min values.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Did you read [How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for pointing out to the reference. Now, I know the method to use is `scat.set_array(array)`. However, I tried to include it on my code, but before I need to normalize my data respect to the global color map. I tried to include a similar line as `color_update = [cmap(normalize(value)) for value in data.z]` inside of the `update_graph(num, graph, cmap, normalize)` function but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: The main difference is that you specify the colors themselves, while you would rather use the `c` argument and supply the values directly, just as shown in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I got the solution (Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the guidance).
The required steps were: 
a) Define the `cmap`, and `normalize` variables to create the "global colormap"
b) Normalize each value of height (Z) for every frame and store the list in an extra slot of the dataframe.
c) Inside of the `update_graph(num)` use the `scat.set_array(array)` to pass the previously normalized values of height.
d) Define the graph by using the `c` argument.
Attached you can see the final code.

```
#Python modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.animation
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

###############################################################################
#Generate data
###############################################################################

np.random.seed(10) #To obtain the same result

n_radii  = 8
n_angles = 120

# Make radii and angles spaces (radius r=0 omitted to eliminate duplication).
radii = np.linspace(0.125, 1.0, n_radii)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)

# Repeat all angles for each radius.
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)

# Convert polar (radii, angles) coords to cartesian (x, y) coords.
# (0, 0) is manually added at this stage,  so there will be no duplicate
# points in the (x, y) plane.
x = np.append(0, (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten())
y = np.append(0, (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten())

rows = len(x)
dim = 3
samples = 5

data = np.zeros((rows,dim,samples)) # (20 xyz) points stored in 10 sets 

for i in range(samples):
    data[:,0,i] = x
    data[:,1,i] = y
    # Compute z to make the pringle surface.
    data[:,2,i] = np.sin(-i*x*y)

index = np.arange(0,samples,1)

Frame = np.array([np.ones(rows)*index[i] for i in range(samples)]).flatten()

a = np.zeros((len(Frame),4))

for i in range(samples):
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,0] = data[:,0,i]
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,1] = data[:,1,i]
    a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,2] = data[:,2,i]

# cmap will generate a tuple of RGBA values for a given number in the range 0.0 to 1.0 
# (also 0 to 255 - not used in this example).
# To map our z values cleanly to this range, we create a Normalize object.
cmap      = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm') #'viridis')#
normalize = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(a[:,2]), vmax=max(a[:,2]))

colors    = [cmap(normalize(value)) for value in data[:,2,-1]]
color_list= []

for i in range(samples):
   color_temp = [normalize(value) for value in data[:,2,i]]
   color_list = color_list + color_temp 

df = pd.DataFrame({"Frame": Frame ,"x" : a[:,0], "y" : a[:,1], "z" : a[:,2], "colors":color_list})

##############################################################################
#SCATTER PLOT
################################################################################

#Function to update my scatter plot
def update_graph(num):

    data_plot = df[df['Frame'] == index[num]]
    graph._offsets3d = (data_plot.x, data_plot.y, data_plot.z) #Update data
    graph.set_array(data_plot.colors) #Update colors

    title.set_text(r'How to update the color map for each plot based on the value of, Frame={}'.format(round(index[num],3)))

    return

#Limits of Elevation (U3) in data
print('U3_min',min(a[:,2]))
print('U3_max',max(a[:,2]))

#Define figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=200)

title = plt.suptitle(r'How to update the color map for each plot based on the value of, Frame={}'.format(round(index[0],3), fontsize=16))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(45,30)
ax1.set_xlabel('X (mm)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y (mm)')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z Elevation (mm)')

data_plot = df[df['Frame']==1]
graph     = ax1.scatter(data_plot.x, data_plot.y, data_plot.z, cmap=cmap, c=data_plot.colors, edgecolors='none')

## Optionally add a colorbar
cax, _ = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax1, shrink=0.5)
cbar   = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=normalize, extend='both')

#Animation
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frames = range(samples),) 


plt.show()
```