# Animate 2 different plots on top of each other with Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, animation

SO I am have animated a series of frames with `Matplotlib`. Now there is a specific point for every frame that I want to mark with a red dot. I have the index of the dot of every frame in a list. How can I add the plotting of the dot to the animation. 
here is my code:
`data_clean` is the main data that I'm already animating. `pred` is the list that contains the dots.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) 

ax= fig.add_subplot(111,xlabel='Range bins', ylabel='Doppler bins' )
im = ax.imshow(data_clean[0,0,...], vmin= -60, vmax=0, animated=True)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_label('dB Full Scale')
#this should scatter the dot
im4 = plt.scatter(*pred[:,0], color="r")


def animate(i):
    im3.set_array(data_clean[i,0])
    im4.set_array(pred[:,i])
    return im3, im4


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=50, interval=50, blit=False, repeat=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot)

Comment: @DizietAsahi I dont have problem to plot a scatter. my problem is to plot the scatter and the image on top of each other. Like ploting to different lines in the same figure.