# How to animate multiple points moving using funcanimation (not ax.scatter())?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simulation

I have the code below. If you run that program a scatter plot is created. The plot is very messy. I want every point to represent one car. I only want to see the point of the current position of each car in the animation. I am not very good at matplotlib, but how would I do that?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import math
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

roadLength    = 100
numFrames     = 200

numCars = 60
velocities = []
positions     = []
theta         = []
r             = []
color         = []
probability = 0.5
vmax = 1
flowr = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.axis('off')


for i in range(numCars):
    positions.append(i * 2)
    theta.append(0)
    r.append(1)
    color.append(i)
    velocities.append(0)


def pos(k):
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)
    if velocities[k] < vmax:
        velocities[k] +=  1
    if k < numCars-1 and (positions[k+1] - positions[k]) <= velocities[k]:
        velocities[k] = positions[k+1] - positions[k] - 1
    if k == numCars-1 and (roadLength - (positions[k] - positions[0])) <= velocities[k]:
        velocities[k] = roadLength - (positions[k] - positions[0]) - 1

    if rand < probability and velocities[k] > 0:
        velocities[k] = velocities[k] - 1
    positions[k] = positions[k] + velocities[k]
    return positions[k]




def animate(frameNr):
    for i in range(numCars):
        theta[i] = pos(i) * 2 * math.pi / roadLength
        flowr.append(velocities[i])
    ax.scatter(theta, r, c=color)
    return ax.scatter(theta, r, c=color),


def simulate():
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=numFrames, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)

    plt.show()

simulate()
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I fixed so that it became a point plot I am now storing velocity, position and lane in an object for a later problem. My question is:
How do I make the points have different colors?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import math
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
from operator import attrgetter

roadLength    = 100
numFrames     = 200
nlanes = 1
numCars = 20
posss =[]
theta         = []
r             = []
color         = []
probability = 0.5
vmax = 1
flowr = []
cars=[]


class Car:
    def __init__(self, position, velocity, lane):
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.lane = lane






def pos(car,k):
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)
    if car[k].velocity < vmax:
        car[k].velocity +=  1
    if k < numCars-1 and (car[k+1].position - car[k].position) <= car[k].velocity:
        car[k].velocity = car[k+1].position - car[k].position - 1
    if k == numCars-1 and (roadLength - (car[k].position - car[0].position)) <= car[k].velocity:
        car[k].velocity = roadLength - (car[k].position - car[0].position) - 1

    if rand < probability and car[k].velocity > 0:
        car[k].velocity = car[k].velocity - 1
    car[k].position = car[k].position + car[k].velocity
    return car[k].position

for i in range(numCars):
    cars.append(Car(i, 0, 1))
    theta.append(0)
    r.append(1)
    color.append(i)
    posss.append(i)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
point, = ax.plot(posss, r, 'o')
ax.set_xlim(-10, 1.2*numFrames)
ax.set_ylim(-2, nlanes + 3)

def animate(frameNr):
    sort_cars = sorted(cars, key=attrgetter("position"))
    for i in range(numCars):
        pos(sort_cars,i)
    for k in range(numCars):
        theta[k]=cars[k].position


    point.set_data(theta, r)
    return point,


def simulate():
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=numFrames, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)

    plt.show()

simulate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plot()` returns a `Line2D` object, in which all points have the same color.

If you want your points to have different colors, you should use `scatter()`. The logic is exactly the same, except you use `set_offsets(<2D array>)` instead of `set_data()`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot) for more details