# How can I update a plot without creating multiple figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-3d

I am using Python 3.9 in Spyder and have a problem with plotting.
Whenever I plot something, in the "Plot" Pane, a new plot pops up.

For my application, I want to update the plot very quickly but every time I plot the figure, a new figure appears in the "Plot" Pane and after 500 plots it gets very laggy.
With hours of searching on the web, I have found no good way to do it.

Ideally, the plot contents should just be removed and not the figure or axes.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Module for plotting data
import time # Module for acquiring times

for i in range(1,11):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
    
    ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
    ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    ax.set_zlim(-10,10)
    
    ax.quiver(0,0,0,i,i,i)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Its very straight forwards and easy, but all it produces is 10 individual plots in the "Plot" pane (I muted Inline Plotting).
Preferably, I would have one plot which just updates, either in the "Plot" Pane of Spyder or as a seperate window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

for i in range(1,11):
   
    ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
    ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    ax.set_zlim(-10,10)
    ax.quiver(0,0,0,i,i,i)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.01)
    ax.clear()
```

The plot will get updated every 0.01 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I had to add "import matplotlib" and  matplotlib.use('TkAgg')" in front of your code to make it work. But it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: On another note: How to close the figure? I've searched the internet for an hour, but I cant find a way to close the figure without having to force it to shut down. Its "not responding" after the last plot.

Comment: @FF `plt.close()`?

Comment: Sorry, plt.close() does not do anything.

Comment: @FF `plt.close(fig)`?

Answer (score 0):

Updating an existing plot usually entails creating a [matplotlib-animation](/questions/tagged/matplotlib-animation).

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68868815/7758804).

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

def update(i):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
    ax.set_zlim(-10, 10)
    ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10)
        
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=11, interval=1)

# this is not needed unless you want to save the file
# ani.save('quiver.gif', writer='pillow')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately your code does not work in my Python...
Just plain like you posted, it doesn't do anything besides plotting the last plot in the "Plot" Pane of Spyder.